# Keep getting the OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "0") Warning

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

Ok.  So I am using the below JSP and Java code to access the `notMessageFieldList`.  It works fine, however, I keep getting a `OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "0")` warning when I leave the page. It seems that Struts 2 is trying to get *null* values and triggers this warning.  Is there any way to get rid of it without adjusting my Tomcat settings?

JSP:

```
        <s:iterator var="counter" begin="0" end="3">
        <tr>
            <th style="font-size: 120%; font-weight: 900; color: red;">X</th>
            <td style="font-size: 80%;">NEW</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Field Name:</b>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="float: left">
                <s:textfield
                        name="notMessageFieldList[%{counter}].tag"
                        size="47">
                </s:textfield>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Description:</b>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="float: left">
                <s:textfield
                        name="notMessageFieldList[%{counter}].description"
                        size="47">
                </s:textfield>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Data Type:</b>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="float: left">
                <s:select
                        list="validDataTypes"
                        name="notMessageFieldList[%{counter}].dataType"
                        key="dataType.required"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
```

JAVA ACTION:

```
private List<NotificationMessageField> notMessageFieldList = new ArrayList<>(4);

public List<NotificationMessageField> getNotMessageFieldList() {
        return notMessageFieldList;
    }

public void setNotMessageFieldList(@Nullable final List<NotificationMessageField> notMessageFieldList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmptyList(notMessageFieldList)) {
        this.notMessageFieldList.clear();
        this.notMessageFieldList = new ArrayList<>(notMessageFieldList);
    } else {
        this.notMessageFieldList = new ArrayList<>(5);
    }
}
```

JAVA POJO (Assume regular set up, getters/setters):

```
public NotificationMessageField(final String tag, final String description, final String dataType) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.description = description;
    this.dataType = dataType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the value attribute to textfields. It will preset textfields with the initial value and once the value is preset it won't be evaluated by the name.

```
<s:textfield name="notMessageFieldList[%{counter}].tag" size="47" value="">
```

Comment: @ Roman C: Thanks for trying, but its still throwing the warning. I will just have to keep "fiddling" with it. Fortunately, it is not throwing a full error and stopping the application, it just throws a bunch of warnings . . . which allows me a little more time to get to the bottom.

Comment: @Mike You can post the warnings, but if it's the same warnings that it wouldn't to resolve. According the information you provided it's not possible to tell you why this happens. What I can suggest you is to debug the issue on property `notMessageFieldList` and check where it's not initialized.